# SQLite multiple UPDATES in one query

Tags: sql, sqlite

In table Colors, there is a Color column. I need to make 5 updates to the values in this column based on different conditions.

```
SET Color = 'Blue' WHERE Color = 'blue'  
SET Color = 'Green' WHERE Color = 'green'  
SET Color = 'Yellow' WHERE Color = 'yellow'  
SET Color = 'Brown' WHERE Color = 'brown'  
SET Color = 'Orange' WHERE Color = 'orange'
```

Can I make these 5 updates to the table in one query?

**Note:** my real values are more complex than this, so disregard simple functions to make the values uppercase

Comment: i dont think so it's possible, you should write separate queries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of `CASE` expression and decide which value you want to set to `Color`.

```
UPDATE [YourSchema].[Colors] 
SET     Color=  CASE  
                        WHEN Color = 'blue'  THEN 'Blue' 
                        WHEN Color = 'green'  THEN 'Green' 
                        WHEN Color = 'yellow'  THEN 'Yellow' 
                        WHEN Color = 'brown'  THEN 'Brown' 
                        WHEN Color = 'orange'  THEN 'Orange' 
                    END
 WHERE Color IN ('blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'brown', 'orange')
```

**Note:** If you are having default schema then use `dbo.Colors` as the table name,

Comment: You should probably add on a `WHERE` clause so the `UPDATE` only acts on records containing colors which should be modified.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oops.. thanx.. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to a lengthy `CASE` expression, you can simply do a conditional uppercasing of the first letter of a color should that color match the ones you gave in your list.

```
update Colors
set Color = upper(substr(Color, 1, 1)) || substr(Color, 2)
where Color in ('blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'brown', 'orange')
```

Comment: Perfect for this situation - I was really looking for an answer I could apply to more complex values (not just updating values for upper/lower case)

Comment: @Chicowitz Then a `CASE` expression might serve you better in general, but this query fits your current question well.